# Student Loan for International Students in the US

Tags: united-states, student-loan, university

I live and work in NJ. I am getting ready for a Part Time Program to enhance my career. University has clearly mentioned me that they will not provide any Scholarships. I am responsible to find the Financial Aid by myself.

I am willing to get better advise on finding private Student Loans.

Comment: The financial aid office can tell you some of the loans available, even if they aren't giving you any scholarship money.

Answer (score 1):

You have several sources of money:

- Scholarships not directly from the university. Some organizations have scholarships based on your area of study, your nationality, or your industry. Some require you to show that you need the money, others are based on your grades. The university can help you find these scholarship, or at least point you towards reliable listings. Don't pay somebody/some company to help you find them.
- Your employer. Some companies will pay for some classes. They may limit the types of the classes, and the amount of money. They may also require you to stay as an employee for a specific number of years in return for the money. If you quit before that time,they can ask you to refund the money.
- loans. I don't know what loan programs are available for international students.

Comment: I work as a Contract Employee. So, I know that my employer will not pay for it. I am not sure of scholarships will help me .. As because of foreign nationality as well as having a full time job.I am more keen on getting a loan !!